# POSIX shell compliant method to find matching line with HTML element by name, then extract HTML element value

Tags: html, regex, forms, shell, sed

POSIX shell compliant method to find matching line with HTML element by name, then extract HTML element value

**Input Data Source**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>

<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <div class='wrapper'>
        <div class='float1'>
          <form id="form1" action="/endpoint" method="post">
            <input name="input1" type="hidden" value="value1" />
            <fieldset>
              <input id="input2" name="input2" value="value2">
              <input id="input3" name="input3" value="value3">
            </fieldset>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
  </main>

  <footer>
  </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

**Output required**

```
value1
value2
value3
```

**Logic required**

1. Find input element with name equal to "input1"
2. For this element, extract value contents

**Preferences**

- SED or AWK would be preferred answer. Unsure of any other POSIX compliant method which could parse HTML.
- Command would should be reusable, so multiple Shell variables can use the same command (with a different element name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, never ever use [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) nor [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) to parse HTML nor XML, but a proper [html](/questions/tagged/html) parser.

```
xmllint --xpath \
'string(/form[@id="form1"]/input[@name="input1"]/@value)' file
```

#### Output

```
value1
```

## Edit after OP comments, using broken HTML

```
xidel -s --xpath \
'//form[@id="form1"]//input[starts-with(@name, "input")]/@value' file
```

### Output

```
value1
value2
value3
```

---

Don't parse XML/HTML with regex, use a proper XML/HTML parser and a powerful [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) query.

#### theory :

> According to the compiling theory, XML/HTML can't be parsed using regex based on [finite state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine). Due to hierarchical construction of XML/HTML you need to use a [pushdown automaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton) and manipulate [LALR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LR_parser) grammar using tool like [YACC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yacc).

#### realLife©®™ everyday tool in a [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) :

You can use one of the following :

[xmllint](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html) often installed by default with `libxml2`, xpath1 (check [my wrapper](https://github.com/sputnick-dev/xmllint) to have newlines delimited output

[xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/docs.php) can edit, select, transform... Not installed by default, xpath1

[xpath](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::XPath) installed via perl's module XML::XPath, xpath1

[xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html) xpath3

[saxon-lint](https://github.com/sputnick-dev/saxon-lint) my own project, wrapper over @Michael Kay's Saxon-HE Java library, xpath3

#### or you can use high level languages and proper libs, I think of :

[python](/questions/tagged/python)'s [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/) (`from lxml import etree`)

[perl](/questions/tagged/perl)'s [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-LibXML/LibXML.pod), [`XML::XPath`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::XPath), [`XML::Twig::XPath`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig), [`HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath`](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath)

[ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) [nokogiri](/questions/tagged/nokogiri), [check this example](https://sputnick.fr/scripts/parsing-HTML-with-NokogiriXpath.rb.html)

[php](/questions/tagged/php) `DOMXpath`, [check this example](https://sputnick.fr/scripts/parsing-HTML-with-DOMXpath.php.html)

---

Check: [Using regular expressions with HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

[image]

Comment: It lints the file, it doesn't show an output result.  There are lots of "parser error" about "Opening and ending tag mismatch" and a few "xmlParseEntityRef: no name" errors also.   Even trying to explicitly state the path in the command still results in linting errors  `xmllint --xpath 'string(/html/body/main/div/div/div/div/div/form[@id="form1"]/input[@name="input1"]/@value)' file`.   Although explicitly stating the path would be an unsatisfactory command, as the file could dynamically change

Comment: Adding html operator `xmllint --html --xpath` resolves all but 2 linting errors which are `Tag main invalid` and `Tag footer invalid`. Still cannot make the this resolve, I will update the Data Source in original question to be more accurate with scenario

Comment: POST edited accordingly, added `xidel` way for broken HTML

Comment: xidel worked, although this adds an additional package required to the OS beyond initial installation in POSIX environment. Agree this is a more manageable solution than sed or awk.